# Application error after project is deployed on Heroku using flask

Tags: flask, heroku, gunicorn, procfile

[image]

my project is running successfully on local server so i am pretty sure the error has something to do wit Procfile, I have looked up every and found two ways of coding this. can anyone please tell me which is the correct way?

[image]

Keep in mind this project uses flask not Django so there is no wsgi file, the folder structure looks something like this.
[image]

the error code is H10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and let me know it works or not

```
web: gunicorn -w 4 -b "0.0.0.0:$PORT" app:app
```

and create a file `runtime.txt` and add this in it

```
python-3.8.2
```

Comment: gave the same error again bro, it gives a file not found error? can u tell me how to upload  tsv files on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change EOL format of your Procfile from Windows to unix, then deploy it again.

You can change it using notepad++ or sublime text .